# Multiple Value Selection / Deselection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uibutton

I have multiple values for user selection.

When user selects multiple options then it should be saved in the array.

When user deselects the value then it should remove the same from the array.

How can it be done?

There can be any random selection and deselection from the options.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to do this using a table view, you can maintain an mutable array of selected index paths. You can set accessory type to check mark to indicate selection.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( [array indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound ) {
        [array addObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        [array removeObject:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

and use the array to set the `accessoryType` properly during cell initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model class named **Options** and place all your options as member variables. Update these variables when a user changes the value for any option. Use this variable to port your data from one object to other. Hope this will help you. If it is necessary for you to store the values in a Array then give me some more details about your requirement so we can think further.